# Can't find a way to access input field with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a way to change the value of the input field
below using Javascript. The problem is that I can't find any
id or name of the input field and thus, not sure how to access it.

I have used document.getElementById to access other fields to change
their value but since this input field does not have an Id I'm not sure
how to approach it. The code below is not my own and thus I can't simply
add an id. Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

```
<ul class="form-control recipient-input ac-input rounded-left">
 <li class="input">
  <input type="text" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria- expanded="false" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false">
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` for targetting the same element with different attributes. You can even use a list of attributes aswell

```js
const node1 = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
console.log(node1);
const node2 = document.querySelector('input[tabindex="1"]');
console.log(node2);
const node3 = document.querySelector('input[autocomplete="off"]');
console.log(node3);
const node4 = document.querySelector('input[aria-autocomplete="list"]');
console.log(node4);
const node5 = document.querySelector('input[aria-expanded="false"]');
console.log(node5);
const node6 = document.querySelector('input[role="combobox"]');
console.log(node6);
const node7 = document.querySelector('input[aria-haspopup="false"]');
console.log(node7);
const node8 = document.querySelector('input[type="text"][tabindex="1"][autocomplete="off"][aria-autocomplete="list"][aria-expanded="false"][role="combobox"][aria-haspopup="false"]');
console.log(node8);
```

```html
<ul class="form-control recipient-input ac-input rounded-left">
  <li class="input">
    <input type="text" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you this worked for inputing text. I now have a new problem tho. The input field is used to type in an email recipient. When I change the value of the field the recipient I chose does not get registered. The site does not recognize that any email has been input even though I can see the email in the text field. When I type an email manually a new code snipet gets generated. 

<li class="recipient">
 <span class="name">asd@gmail.com</span>
 <span class="email">,</span>
 <a class="button icon remove"></a>
</li>

Answer (score 0):

```js
const el = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
console.log(el)
```

```html
<ul class="form-control recipient-input ac-input rounded-left">
 <li class="input">
  <input type="text" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria- expanded="false" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false">
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input />` elements should always be enclosed within a `<form />`.

By giving a `name` to your `<form name="my-form"><input name="firstName" /></form>`, it become easy to access any fields of the form without having to use fixed `id` in your HTML and make those `<form />` reusable anywhere in your view.

```js
window.onload = bindEvents

function bindEvents() {
  const { name } = document.forms['my-form']
  name.addEventListener('keypress', onChangeName, true)
}

function onChangeName(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input name="name" />
   </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: `const {name} = document.forms['my-form'];` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I think "document.querySelector" is enough to do that job. Below code might be useful.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var elm = document.querySelector('.recipient-input input');
    // Get the full DOM object of input element 
    console.log(elm);    
    
    // Get input value
    var val = elm.value;
    console.log(val);
    
    // Get any attribute
    var attr  = elm.getAttribute("role");
    console.log(attr);
    
    // Set input value
    elm.value = "This is a form element";
    console.log(elm.value);
    
    // Change any attribute
    elm.setAttribute("role", "primary");
    console.log(elm.getAttribute("role")); 
});
```

```html
<ul class="form-control recipient-input ac-input rounded-left">
 <li class="input">
  <input type="text" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria- expanded="false" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false">
 </li>
</ul>
```